# Is there a problem with the way I am implementing OOP into my python MakeCode Maqueen robot?

Tags: python, oop, makecode

Me and my friend are working on a school project where we need to make a "BattleBot" out of our maqueen. I am using this opportunity to teach my friend OOP (he has less experience in programming), so I am trying to make the bot as a class.

We tested the maqueens to make sure you can use classes (which you can), and that our function works (which it does).

Here is a minimal reproducible example to our code -

```
class Battlebot:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    # Bob and Weave
    def bob_weave(self):
        rand_itterations = randint(2,7)
        for i in range(rand_itterations):
            # Generate Random Values
            turn_speed = randint(20,100)
            turn_time = randint(50,500)

            move_speed = randint(50,100)
            move_time = randint(50,500)


            # Turn
            maqueen.motor_run(maqueen.Motors.M1, maqueen.Dir.CW, turn_speed)
            maqueen.motor_run(maqueen.Motors.M2, maqueen.Dir.CCW, turn_speed)

            basic.pause(turn_time)
            maqueen.motor_stop(maqueen.Motors.ALL)


            # Move
            maqueen.motor_run(maqueen.Motors.M1, maqueen.Dir.CW, move_speed)
            maqueen.motor_run(maqueen.Motors.M2, maqueen.Dir.CW, move_speed)

            basic.pause(move_time)
            maqueen.motor_stop(maqueen.Motors.ALL)


fwire_immigrant = Battlebot()

def on_forever():
    fwire_immigrant.bob_weave()

basic.forever(on_forever)
```

We are using the [MakeCode website](https://makecode.microbit.org/#).

Comment: why is there an `__init__` method defined if all you do is `pass`? so, your class doesnt seem to use any internal state, so it doesn't really make sense to make it a class.

Comment: I didnt realise that __init__ methods arent required my bad. I'll try it when I get back to school tomorrow.